# Simple dom traversal using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom-traversal

I am working with a prior developers star rating code. I need to modify it because it doesn't operate the way the developer intended. If you look, there are `label` elements with stars inside. You can see the first `label` has 1 `span`, while the 5th  `label` has 5 `spans`.

An example of how it's working now is you click on the 5th `input` the developer has 5 stars inside the `label`, but to get it to work as intended **I actually need to modify the other label spans as well**. So, let's say the user chooses 3 stars, I'd need to mutate the `span` inside labels 1, 2, and 3. For choosing 4 stars, I'd need to mutate the `span` inside labels 1, 2, 3, and 4.

I was thinking about a jquery/javascript solution that traverses labels (maybe with ids). So if they click on input 4, the javascript solution would loop through all spans inside labels 1, 2, 3, and 4 and update the css. I'm not sure how to do this though.

```
<div class="rating-selector">
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="rating" value="1" />
        <span class="icon">★</span>
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="rating" value="2" />
        <span class="icon">★</span>
        <span class="icon">★</span>
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="rating" value="3" />
        <span class="icon">★</span>
        <span class="icon">★</span>
        <span class="icon">★</span>   
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="rating" value="4" />
        <span class="icon">★</span>
        <span class="icon">★</span>
        <span class="icon">★</span>
        <span class="icon">★</span>
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="rating" value="5" />
        <span class="icon">★</span>
        <span class="icon">★</span>
        <span class="icon">★</span>
        <span class="icon">★</span>
        <span class="icon">★</span>
    </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could find the parent `<label>` index by using `.closest("label").index()`. Then, use the [`:lt()` selector](https://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/) to grab each item before it.

```js
const highlightPrevious = (elem) => {
  let $this = $(elem);
  $(".rating-selector label span").css("color", "");                 //reset styling
  let idx = $this.index();                                           //get index of selected label
  $(`.rating-selector label:lt(${idx+1}) span`).css("color", "red"); //style all label spans up to and including the selected index
};

$('label')
  .click(function() { highlightPrevious(this); })
  .mouseover(function() { $(this).click() });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="rating-selector">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="rating" value="1" />
    <span class="icon">★</span>
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="rating" value="2" />
    <span class="icon">★</span>
    <span class="icon">★</span>
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="rating" value="3" />
    <span class="icon">★</span>
    <span class="icon">★</span>
    <span class="icon">★</span>   
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="rating" value="4" />
    <span class="icon">★</span>
    <span class="icon">★</span>
    <span class="icon">★</span>
    <span class="icon">★</span>
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="rating" value="5" />
    <span class="icon">★</span>
    <span class="icon">★</span>
    <span class="icon">★</span>
    <span class="icon">★</span>
    <span class="icon">★</span>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: can you explain why you use a tick instead of an apostrophe? works great though.

Comment: also, how would you implement going in the reverse order? when the page loads, if they hover over the 5th star, currently the prior dont shine

Comment: I tried adding $(":radio").click with $(":radio").hover no luck but i dont think this is correct it might cause a race condition with the click

Comment: I'm not clear what you mean about "reverse order". And are you saying you want to replace the `click` event with `hover`?

Comment: what im saying is when you initially load the page, and you attempt at clicking the 5th star from a hover, the 4 prior stars dont get enabled. the click portion works great though.

Comment: Please see my edit and let me know if that's closer.

Comment: Works fantastic. My only remaining question is when you hover over the stars it doesnt emulate a click. Is  there a way to make it so if they hover over the 5th star it would make it checked. I imagine some logic would be to make sure if they go to the 5th then hover back to the 3rd star the 3rd star would be clicked and the others wouldnt. i tried `$('.starlabel input[name=rating]').prop('checked',false);` to clear the inputs (i added the class starlabel to the label elements. i also did `$this.children().first().prop('checked',true);` inside the highlightPrevious function

Comment: fyi `$('label')` is now `$('.starlabel')` so it doesnt activate when hovering over non related labels

Comment: @jkushner See my edit and let me know if it's correct. You can edit `label` to `.starlabel` where necessary for your use-case.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simpler pure CSS solution:

```css
.rating-selector {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 0;
  direction: rtl;
}

input[name="rating"] {
  display: none;
}

input[name="rating"]~label {
  color: grey
}

input[name="rating"]:checked~label {
  color: gold
}
```

```html
<fieldset class="rating-selector">
  <input type="radio" name="rating" value="5" id="rating-5" />
  <label for="rating-5">★</label>
  <input type="radio" name="rating" value="4" id="rating-4" />
  <label for="rating-4">★</label>
  <input type="radio" name="rating" value="3" id="rating-3" />
  <label for="rating-3">★</label>
  <input type="radio" name="rating" value="2" id="rating-2" />
  <label for="rating-2">★</label>
  <input type="radio" name="rating" value="1" id="rating-1" />
  <label for="rating-1">★</label>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: I don't believe the first example is accomplishing quite what OP wants, but I may be wrong. *"So if they click on input 4, the javascript solution would loop through all spans **inside labels 1, 2, 3, and 4** and update the css."* - Your solution only modifies spans inside the *selected* label, not those that precede it.

Comment: @Santi, you're absolutely right, OP wants to fix weird implementation with a weird approach. I would replace it completely. =))

Comment: @KoshVery i agree completely but im not reimplementing someones code id prefer to just fix.

Comment: @jkushner, It's up to you, surely.

Comment: its tied to too many other components reimplementing would be a bigger nightmare but i totally agree i was like man i just want to redo this

Comment: @jkushner, looks like you have to deal with a spaghetti monster.. Wish you win in this fight! =))